# How to easily tell if Ninject can resolve a class

Tags: c#, ioc-container, ninject

I'm introducing Ninject into a large mess of a existing project. I want to write a diagnostic test to make sure that all of the classes Ninject will end up creating can actually BE resolved by Ninject...without actually creating any of them.

The reason I want to avoid the actual construction is that many of these classes have a tendency to start up database operations in their constructors (*sigh* yes I know). Otherwise I would just run them all through `Get<T>` with a try/catch

Answer (score 5):

There's a `CanResolve` extension on `IResolutionRoot` (i.e., you can use it against `Kernel` if you have the right `using`s in place). There's a `CreateRequest` that you use to create the request. Have a look in the sources and tests if you need an example or any deeper information.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but it was the first one I found when searching for how to find if a class can be resolved by Ninject without actually calling get() and risking an exception.

Ninject version 3.0.2 have a method CanResolve which returns a boolean:

```
kernel.CanResolve<T>()
```

I got 3.0.2 from nuget but its currently market unstable (Ninject.3.0.2-unstable-9037) so I'm not sure if I use this in production just yet.

Comment: Unfortunally, `CanResolve` does not look into the resolution tree. So if it is missing a binding on a second order dependency, it will not tell you.